# what should i store colors as in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I am storing things in a sqlite database.  One of its attributes is a color.  When I display this, I want to do

```
objLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(some_int)
```

Normally I'd use R.color.red in place of some_int.  However, I am persisting the color, and I think the R file generates a new id for red each time I run the app, making that method not feasible.  I could store the string representation, like "red", and in my java code check for the color string and apply the correct R.color, but that looks ugly.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: What about the hex and using some other function to convert to whatever other format you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store hex codes and use it when you set colors. 
Like `ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));`

Here's some good explanation on the comments of another question.

[Changing Color with LinearLayout and TextView in Java (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715593/changing-color-with-linearlayout-and-textview-in-java-android)

Answer (score 5):

You should not be storing the values from R (i.e. `R.color.red`) in any kind of permanent storage. The value is regenerated on every app build, so if an update is put out what used to be `R.color.red` is now `R.color.purple` or worse `R.layout.activity_main`.

What you could do is store the resolved color in the SQLite database (`getResources().getColor(R.color.red)`) since that is just a integer representing a color, not a pointer to a color. That way if you eventually change `R.color.red` from #F00 to #E00, the value saved will be #F00.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the name of the color in your DB, you can use getIdentifier method.

For example:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
int colorId = resources.getIdentifier("your_color_name", "color", getPackageName());
```